# kops no such host in route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-route53, kops

I try to create cluster with kops. I buy domain name in aws route53 megatest.com in I created public Hosted zones.

```
megatest.com.
NS
ns-1092.awsdns-08.org. 
ns-1917.awsdns-47.co.uk. 
ns-69.awsdns-08.com. 
ns-801.awsdns-36.net.

megatest.com.
SOA
ns-801.awsdns-36.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com.
```

but when I a want to create my cluster I have this error

> error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "artistesemergents.com": lookup artistesemergents.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

The command that I use looks like this

```
kops create cluster --name=megatest.com --state=s3://kops-state-megatest123 --zones=us-east-1a --node-count=3 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro --dns-zone=megatest.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your Hosted zones aws does not change your name server in your Registered domains.

Click on your domain in Registered domains after change your name server with the new name server on your host zones.

Answer (score 0):

keep the name and hostnames in Environment variables when you change anything in .bashrc dont forget to exit and go to root
try to execute kops validate cluster it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).